# Using inner function variable in outer function using Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-api-javascript-client

I am fairly new to Javascript so forgive me if this has been answered but I cannot get this to work  nor can I find the answer anywhere online. I am trying to return an address using Google's Maps JavaScript API. I can print it to the console inside the inner function but if I try to access it outside of that function, it is printing undefined. How can I access the variable in the outer function and return it??

```
    function getAddress(latlng) {
        var address;
        var service = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        
        service.geocode({ location: latlng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === "OK") {
                if (results[0]) {
                    address = results[0].formatted_address;
                    console.log(address); //prints address
                } 
            }
        });
        console.log(address); //prints undefined
    }
```

Comment: it's asynchronous, that's why there is a callback. You can't log outside the callback, you gotta wait for the callback to finish.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How is this achieved though? Again, sorry fairly new to this.

Comment: you have at least 3 options: 1 log the address at the end of the callback within the two `if` statements, that's when you know you have an address - 2 return a promise that resolves once the address is retrieved (or rejects otherwise) - 3 return a function that will be invoked once the address is retrieved ... if you want examples, I need to write a proper answer. Do you need it?

Comment: That would be very helpful. I have some sort of idea on how to implement option 2 and tried it but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a classic asynchronous gotcha, where `address` is available only once the callback is invoked, where usually, when a callback is needed, it means there are no guarantees its result will be available outside its execution, and since I believe there is a network request involved, there's no way the result can arrive in time for you to log `address` right after.

```
var value;
api.thing(callbackThatSetsValue)
console.log(value);
```

The gits of the problem is there: `value` can't point at anything, as the `callbackThatSetsValue` will be invoked after the next line of code gets executed.

There are at least 2 options here, let's see how these look like ...

**Wait for the result**

This options allows you to do anything you need once the address is resolved.

```
function getAddress(latlng, after) {
  var service = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  service.geocode({ location: latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === "OK")
      if (results[0])
        after(results[0].formatted_address);
  });
}
```

Above utility allows you to `getAddress({lat:50,lng:1}, console.log)`, as example, or pass any callback that should render, use, display, such address.

The pitfall in this approach is that if `status` is not `OK`, you have a hanging callback forever, as it won't ever get invoked.

Alternatively, you can put an `else` in that function and pass an error, or `null`, and react accordingly in the callback.

**The Promise way**

Is the most common pattern these days, hence my suggestion.

```
function getAddress(latlng) {
  return new Promise(function ($, _) {
    var service = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    service.geocode({ location: latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === "OK")
        if (results[0])
          $(results[0].formatted_address);
      _(new Error("status was " + status));
    });
  });
}
```

In this case you `getAddress({lat:50,lng:1}).then(console.log).catch(console.error)`, so you have an escape/way to react when address is not valid.